# Why would this div have an unnecessarily large computed height?

Tags: css, layout, html, height

Link: http://www.fraynepainting.com/services

The problem is that div#dditem_2 (the div with the "Take a look..." text) is getting a computed height of around 500px for no reason that I can find in the CSS, which is pushing the UL below it down really really far.

I discovered that if you set `display: none` or `position: absolute` (or anything else that removes it from the flow of elements) on the sidebar, then the bottom UL moves up like it should, so it looks like maybe the UL is trying to clear the sidebar, but I can't figure out why that would be either.

I've reproduced the problem in Firefox and Chrome so far. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to the following rule in `v2basic.1263412699.css`:

```
.overwrap .button-bar:after,#content .item:after,#content .blogcomment:after
{
  content:".";
  display:block;height:0;clear:both;visibility:hidden
}
```

Remove `content:".";` from this rule or remove the class `item` from `#dditem_2`.  Not sure what it's there for, but it's making the height go crazy.

Comment: #dditem_2 has class="item html 3" so I searched your styles for definitions for .item (the classes html and 3 are bogus). There was only a few rules for .item and content was the only one out of the ordinary, so I removed it with Firebug to verify.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a lot of divs. Did you try putting border: 1px solid red around the divs to see where they may be touching?

Comment: Yeah, it's coming from a CMS that's more or less out of my control. I used Firefox web dev toolbar to outline divs and that hasn't really given any clues.